# Changing the Base Ring of a Weyl Algebra by Extension of Scalars

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ and $S$ be commutative rings such that there is a homomorphism $\varphi: R \to S$, and let $A_n(R)$ be the $n$-th Weyl algebra over $R$. If we extend the scalars on $A_n(R)$, is it true that

\begin{equation} A_n(R) \otimes_R S \cong A_n(S) \end{equation}

as $S$-algebras?

I believe I have a partial proof. We have an $S$-algebra homomorphism $\theta: A_n(R) \otimes_R S \to A_n(S)$ given by $x_i \otimes s \mapsto sx_i$ and $y_i \otimes s \mapsto sy_i$, where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the generators of the Weyl algebra (I'll omit checking well-definition and that this is a homomorphism).
In the case where $R$ has characteristic $0$, this is surjective since any element in $A_n(S)$ has the form

\begin{equation} 
\sum_{i,j,k,l} s_{ijkl} x_i^k y_j^l 
= \theta \left (\sum_{i,j,k,l}  x_i^k y_j^l \otimes s_{ijkl} \right ),
\end{equation}

and where $S$ has characteristic $0$, I think injectivity is clear.  I understand that in positive chracteristic, it's possible that, for instance, $x_i^k = x_i^{k'}$ but $k \neq k'$, and I'm not entirely sure how to deal with this. Is my argument correct so far, and does this  extend to positive characteristic?

If this is not true in general, I am particularly interested in the case where $R$ is a finitely generated domain of characteristic $0$ and $S=\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$.

Apologies if I have made any mistakes, my knowledge in this area is mostly self-taught and this is my first Stack Exchange post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question but it was my first on MSE and I thought I should answer it myself since it got some upvotes.

This does indeed work in positive characteristic. Surjectivity follows from the expression in the question. Injectivity is also fine; it's still true in positive characteristic that $x_i^k = x_i^{k'}\implies k=k'$ since the $x_i$ and $y_j$ are generators and the only relation is $[x_i,y_j]=\delta_{ij}$.

The properties of $S$ and $R$ mentioned don't affect anything.